# Intent Not Working on Emulator Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

trying to use Email intent on emulator logged in to Gmail on emulator but still, it is not connecting to Gmail.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Order");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,pricemessage);
        if (email.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Mail Using :"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily send email in android via intent. You need to write few lines of code only as given below

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  
       
//need this to prompts email client only  
email.setType("message/cfr893");  
  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When I copied your code, it warned that **Query Permission Needed**. So, add the below code outside of   tag in your manifest.xml file.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" /><data android:scheme="*" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

It works for me after adding it. Let me know if it works for you too.